# Determine if date is before or after the 15th of the month

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function which applies a rate based on the number of months that an item has been stored. However we charge half that rate if the item was stored after the 15th. The function I'm using to determine the amount of months an item is stored is the `DateDiff()` Function. It returns the number of months between two dates. How do I determine if the date is before the 15th or after? If I use `DateDiff(d,1/1/2015, 4/1/15)` I would get a value greater than 15 so I cannot see if the Date is before or after the 15th using greater than or less than 15. How can I determine if either of the dates  (entrance date which is the date the item entered into the storage area and the exit date which is the date it is removed) are before or after the 15th?

Comment: `$date->format('j') >= 15`, assuming $date is a DateTime object and contains whatever date you're wondering about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA models a date as an floating point double. The integral part stands for the day. It advances by 1 per day.

It provides a function `Day(date)` which you can use to extract the day of the month in which `date` occurs.

For example, `CDate(40000)` will return you 6-July-2009, and `Day(40000)` returns you 6.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your suggestion. Could you give me a quick example?

Comment: Makes complete sense, now how would I get my date value to convert to a double? So that I can then pull the date of the month from say 4/1/15?

Comment: A Date/Time value is already a specialized double type, so you don't have to convert it to double in order to extract the day of the month.  For example, `Day(#4/1/2015#)` will return 1, assuming your date format is *m/d/yyyy*.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

`if format(date, "DD") <= 15 then
    msgbox "this is 15 or below"
 else
    msgbox "this is 16 and above"
 end if`

You can put a date variable in instead of `date` which is a built in function to return the system date.